# JS populated AJAX ToolKit ComboBox causes error: "SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

When using javascript/ajax to repopulate the options in ComboBox B based on the selection in ComboBox A, selecting an item in B with an index > original set of indexes causes the error:

"'...' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value "

Evidently comboboxes still link back to their original datasource regardless of what javascript does, so there are issues with it thinking item 1 is x when it's really y, or item 2 doesnt exist. At least that's what I'm getting out of similar posts. What i'm not getting is a solution, tho...

Comment: Are you getting this error on postback or on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ComboBox B was originally populated by databinding, your ViewState is going to reflect that, and your ComboBox B is going to be repopulated from the information in ViewState on postback.  So your SelectedIndex of greater than the original number of items is going to confuse the heck out of it.

(The contents of ComboBoxes don't post back: just the selected item.  So it's not going to know anything about what you did client-side.)

Possible options include:  using an UpdatePanel to update your combo boxes without refreshing the whole page, or making your ComboBox B an ordinary HTML `select`, populating it exclusively from the client side (through Ajax?) and fetching its value from the Forms collection on the server side after postback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Not using combobox isnt an option tho as things should always be way harder than necessary with little to no pay off. Other than that, I like your second suggestion. 

Once I started looking at the forms collection and how to determine what's actually selected, it was more obvious that I just need to give it enough items server side to ensure no index out of bounds error and then work with it (almost) exclusively client side. It's a little wasteful to populate it server side then immediately on the client, but the full list of options is small so it's not an issue